# Visual aspects of JAVASCRIPT and logical aspects of JAVASCRIPT? What is good for a web designer, aspiring to be and UI designer?

Tags: javascript, website-design, jquery, gui

Visual aspects of JAVASCRIPT and logical aspects of JAVASCRIPT? What is good for a web designer, aspiring to be and UI designer?

I am learning Javascript, however, while learning I observed that Javascript has two aspects:

1. Visual - which gives visual effects like, SLIDESHOW.
2. Logical - which gives you some logical effects like, a prompt box.

My question: **I see that there is lot hell to learn in Javascript. I came with a decision to learn only those who have visual effects (As I think, I am not a Javascript programmer, so want to skip some and choose some.)**

**Are my thoughts to choose some (Visual) & skip some (Logical) Javascript aspects, while keeping in mind that I would choose user Interface designing in near future?**

Answer (score 2):

The logical functions of JavaScript support the visual effects. Not only that, but don't try to rush the learning process; There is so much useful aspects of both sides. You will find a great niche if yourself if you are extremely well-rounded.

Comment: So what do you recommend learning in javascript or jquery?